# How to check <aui:validator> object before submitting

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I wrote the following code in aui and i am using the aui validators for fields but here my requirement is while submitting if all validations are success then i want to call one javascript function.How to check erros are there or not in my javascript function.

```
    <aui:form>
    <aui:fieldset id="inputs">
    <aui:input name="staticInput" label="Static Input" value="" size="40" showRequiredLabel="false">
    <aui:validator name="required"/>
    </aui:input>
    </aui:fieldset>

    <aui:button-row>
    <aui:button value="Add Field" cssClass="addField"/>
    <aui:button value="Save" type="submit"/>
    </aui:button-row>
    </aui:form>
<scipt>
function openEmailClient(){
//I want to call this function if all the validations are success
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a custom validator in order to execute a javascript function on correct validation:

```
<aui:input name="staticInput" label="Static Input" value="" size="40" showRequiredLabel="false">

    <aui:validator  name="custom"  errorMessage="please-fill-out-all-required-fields">
        function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
            if (val.length > 0) {
                //open e-mail client
                return true;
            }
            return false;
       }
    </aui:validator>

</aui:input>
```

Comment: Please can you elaborate bit.Where exactly you are checking there are no validation errors.For that one you are saying that need to create new custom rule

Comment: This validator does not check that there are no validation errors, it allows your own implementation of the validation and thus, your own javascript to be executed if there is no error. In the code I posted, you would check that the input "staticInput" has a value with the "val.length > 0" condition before executing your function.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer edit_entry.jsp in liferay sources for bookmark portlet for an example.

In below code, liferay checks for validation errors and calls openEmailClient method only if no validation errors.

```
    <aui:form action="<%= urlToSubmit %>" method="post" name="fm" onSubmit='<%= "event.preventDefault(); " + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "openEmailClient();" %>'>
    <aui:fieldset id="inputs">
    <aui:input name="staticInput" label="Static Input" value="" size="40" showRequiredLabel="false">
    <aui:validator name="required"/>
    </aui:input>
    </aui:fieldset>

    <aui:button-row>
    <aui:button value="Add Field" cssClass="addField"/>
    <aui:button value="Save" type="submit"/>
    </aui:button-row>
    </aui:form>
<scipt>
function <portlet:namespace />openEmailClient(){
//I want to call this function if all the validations are success
}
</script>
```